# How do I disable C# compiler warnings in the HTML area of a razor (Blazor) page?

Tags: blazor, compiler-warnings

I'm getting a null reference warning from a C# line in my Blazor Page.  I don't know how to disable it. I've tried the below and get no compiler errors, but the warning persists.

I would like to disable the warning for this line only. I know how to disable this warning for the project but I like to disable them individually so I can see others if necessary. There is no issue with disabling in the @code block.

```
<td>
    #pragma warning disable CS8604
    @((MarkupString)objInv.Notes)
    #pragma warning restore CS8604
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null reference errors are good - they tell you where your code will fall over if a null value occurs.  In general you don't disable them, you fix the problem.

`var objInv = someservice.GetInv` probably returns a `Inv?` i.e. a object that can be null.

Notes looks like a string so it may well also be null.

`(MarkupString)string` expects `string` to not be null - you can't cast a null!

So to fix your problem you ensure the handler handles nulls gracefully.

```cs
  @((MarkupString)(objInv?.Notes ?? string.Empty ))
```

`objInv?` checks whether `objInv` is null before trying to evaluate `objInv.Notes`.  If it or `Notes` is `null` it returns a `null`.

The null evaluator `??` returns the right hand side value if the left hand side evaluates to null.  Otherwise it returns the left value.

It's just a succinct version of:

```cs
if (objInv is not null && objInv.Notes is not null)
   return (MarkupString)objInv;
else
   return (MarkupString)string.empty;
```

The alternative is to ensure the method that returns `objInv` can't return a null and `objNotes` can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`@((MarkupString)objInv!.Notes)`

Comment: I'm not sure what the ! does.  I did try it and the warning persists.

Comment: `!` (null-forgiving) operator is an operator that simply tell the compiler that you are sure that the value preceeding it is not null. See [! (null-forgiving) operator - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

Comment: Try this `@((MarkupString)objInv!).Notes)` probably there are an issue with precedence between unboxing and ! operator.

Comment: This answer is not correct, nor are the suggestions.  If `objInv` is null, applying the null forgiving operator won't save your program from going bang! An exception will be thrown when the runtime tries to cast a null as a MarkupString. Proof: go to the FetchData page. Add this line `private WeatherForecast forecast;` to the code section. At the top of the page add `@((MarkupString)forecast!.Summary)`. open the page and BANG - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' You need to ensure the value you are casting is a valid string.